# Getting Ruby error "You cannot call create unless the parent is saved"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I've read through several resources but am not having any luck finding an answer. I have the following line of code, which returns "You cannot call create unless the parent is saved":

```
      test.entries.create!({
        :date => date,
        :volume => 15
      })
```

Above this line of code, I have this:

```
  1.upto(5) do |i|
    test = Test.create(
      :name => "test #{i}"
    )
```

Both of these scripts are encapsulated inside one large loop. So the script creates `test` and then creates an entry on `test` using `test.entries.create!`.

However, the script is failing out because the parent has not been saved. It is my understanding that `.create!` does `.new` and `.save`, so the initial `test` should be saved. I have also tried manually putting in `test.save` before the error with no luck. Any thoughts?

Comment: what is `test` in your second block of code. You mean `Test.create`? Also, is there any validations that might be preventing the `save` from happening? Try adding `create!` to the `test.create` instead so it raises an exception if there are any errors.

Comment: I did mean `Test.create` indeed. Adding create! actually gives me more information. My initial code was failing out and I didn't know it, I should be able to take it from here. Feel free to make your comment an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

what is test in your second block of code. You mean Test.create? Also, is there any validations that might be preventing the save from happening?

Try adding create! to the test.create instead so it raises an exception if there are any errors.